# Sugar ORM Migration: Create new table drops/re-creates existing tables

Tags: android, sugarorm

I used SugarORM in my application's first release.
Now, I'm working on the 2nd release, which has new tables added to DB.

According to SugarORM [documentation](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html) "Sugar will automatically create tables for new entities, so your migration script only needs to cater for alterations to existing tables."

Here's what I done:

1. Increased the DB version in the AndroidManifest `<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />`
2. Created the new record class. `public class NewModel extends SugarRecord<NewModel>`

When ran the app, Sugar created the new table, but unfortunately, it also dropped/created existing tables, erasing all data saved locally!

I also tried to create the new table myself, by adding a migration script file `2.sql` which contains my `CREATE TABLE NEW_MODEL` statement. Unfortunately too, it threw an exception "Table already exists" because Sugar created the new table and then tried to run my script!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came to a solution, of which I have to create an empty migration script file with the new version number! Now, it creates the new table without dropping/creating my old tables.

So, to conclude:

1. Increase the DB version number in AndroidManifest.
2. Create your new Sugar record class.
3. Add an empty migration script file named after the new DB version, placed under assets/sugar_upgrades. (ex. 2.sql).

Comment: It's astounding that this is not mentioned in the documentation, caused me alot of headaches..

Comment: It's astounding that a lot of things aren't mentioned in the Sugar documentation...

Comment: where to put the assets folder?